# How does ServiceLoader.load work with class loaders in JPMS?

Tags: java, classloader, java-9, java-module

I have two JPMS layers:

1. Boot layer with `module A` loaded by `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4fca772d`
2. Child layer with `module B` that provides cervices and loaded by `Loader@6b58b9e9`

The parent classloader of `Loader@6b58b9e9` is `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4fca772d`.

In `module A` I have the following code:

```
ServiceLoader<ModuleAInterface> sl = ServiceLoader.load(ModuleAInterface.class);
```

However, the services of `Module B` are found only when context class loader is `Loader@6b58b9e9` and not found when context class loader is `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4fca772d`.

The question - is it possible to get services of `module B` in `module A` without knowing class loader of `module B` in such configuration.

Comment: The class loader or layer that you specify the ServiceLoader.load is the starting point. So yes, if you are specifying a class loader then it should be a loader of one of the modules in the module layer. There is a lot of detail in API docs on this.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thank you for you answer. So, is this statement correct - in child layer we can get parent layer services by child layer module classloader, but we can't get in parent layer child layer services  by parent layer module classloader `in such configuration`?

Comment: @AlanBateman Please, just say - yes or no.

Comment: An example that might is suppose: Suppose an application bundles its own XML parser and suppose both are loaded into a child layer. Application code calls one of the XML APIs (java.xml module in the boot layer) with the class loader provides the context to locate the XML library. Work through that example and you'll see code in the boot layer using ServiceLoader to locate the XML parser in the child layer. I realise this is not a "yes or not" answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the code of `java.util.ServiceLoader` in jdk 14 (see screenshot) it looks like it follows the same logic as class loading when there are multiple `ModuleLayer`, as described in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61233678/979222)

[image]

which means that `ServiceLoader` will  will first look at services in its own `ModuleLayer` then in its parent `ModuleLayer` and continue from child to parent in a recursive manner

> is it possible to get services of module B in module A without knowing class loader of module B in such configuration.

no
but module B can see the services in module A