# What is the relation between ModuleLayer and ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader, java-module

Let's consider the following situation. There are three layers.

```
BootLayer (moduleA)
     |
     |_______Child1(moduleB)
                |
                |__________ Child2(moduleC)
```

Child1 is the child of the BootLayer, Child2 is the child of the Child1.

`Child1` and `Child2` was created by the same code:

```
ClassLoader parentClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
ModuleLayer layer = parentLayer.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, parentClassLoader);
```

As you see the parent class loader of both child layers is SystemClassLoader. However, `moduleB` can use classes of `moduleA`, but `moduleC` can use classes of `moduleA` and `moduleB`.

I am a beginner at classloading, but I've read about `parent-first delegation model`. However, if for both child layers SystemClassLoader is used, then why they see classes from other layers? Could anyone explain?

Comment: A bit more complicated. Modules allow Java to figure out the class loader for a module, without resorting to the parent delegation - they delegate directly to the class loader for that module. It does not matter if the modules are loaded by the same loader or a different loader.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Then why do we pass there parentClassLoader?

Comment: To tell java which class loader it should use for the modules in that layer. It *then*  uses this information to directly delegate to the classloader for that module, bypassing the delegation to the parent.

Comment: The `defineModulesWithOneLoader` javadoc has a lengthy paragraph to explain direct delegation. The parent class loader specified to this method is the class loader to delegate to when the class loader is asked to load a class that does not map to a module.

Comment: @AlanBateman Thank you for you answer. Please, say if the following statement is right/wrong - "1. Firstly classloader of the module tries to find class in the current layer. 2. If it doesn't it tries to find in the parent layers. 3. If it doesn't it tries to find the class using given parentClassLoader"?. I need to understand this algorithm but from javadoc it isn't 100% clear.

Comment: This isn't right. The class loaders created by the defineModulesWithXXX methods do direct delegation. This is completely independent to layers. In your OP there will be load in moduleC that references classes in java.base (mapped boot loader). The "requests" to load these classes will delegate directly to the boot loader.

Comment: The set of observable modules is built when creating the module layer. Java can map a class name (using it's package name) to a module. So if you request to load a class, Java looks up the module that this package belongs to and delegates to the class loader associated with that module.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn If you really understand the topic, could you give a detailed answer explained on fingers? It is not difficult for such clear question, is it?

Comment: @Pavel_K Alan Bateman would be in a better position to write an authoritative answer (google his name + java). But I will try and find the relevant pieces in the documentation and code to write an answer.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Thank you very much. I know that `Alan Bateman` is the best in JPMS but his comments didn't help to understand such important topic that's why I asked a full answer to a clear question.

Comment: While looking for sources for my answer, found [this paragraph](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.6) important: "A run-time module is implicitly part of exactly one layer, by the semantics of defineModules. However, a class loader may create classes in the run-time modules of different layers, because the same class loader may be specified to multiple invocations of defineModules. Access control is governed by a class's run-time module, not by the class loader which created the class or by the layer(s) which the class loader serves. "

Comment: @Pavel_K I don't have cycles to write-up answers here. Can you mail jigsaw-dev with your questions and I'm sure one of us will be happy to reply (and then maybe someone can write an answer here and in other posts so that searching SO finds it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by Alan Bateman in jigsaw-dev mailing list and is posted here.

Module layers are an advanced topic. ClassLoaders are also an advanced topic. When working with module layers and using the `defineModulesWithXXX` methods to create the module layers, then you mostly don't need to be too concerned with class loaders. They are still used to load classes but they are mostly in the background (and not in your face).

You also don't need to be too concerned with the "parent class loader" that you specify to the `defineOneWithOneLoader` method. It's not used when loading classes from modules, it's only when for cases where the code in `moduleB` or `moduleC` tries to load a class that is not in a module, maybe `Class.forName("Foo")` where `Foo` is on the class path. So probably best to ignore the parent class loader when starting out.

The [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModulesWithOneLoader(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.util.List,java.lang.ClassLoader)) explain how the delegation works with modules but maybe it's not clear enough for what is needed here. In your example, support `L1` is the class loader for `moduleB` in child layer 1, and `L2` is the class loader for `moduleC` in child layer 2. Further suppose the module declarations are:

```
module moduleC {
     requires moduleB;
}

module moduleB {
     exports b;
}
```

The configuration for `Child1` is very simple: one `moduleB` that reads `java.base`

The configuration for `Child2` is also very simple: one `moduleC` that reads `moduleB` and `java.base`.

When `Child1` is created it will create `L1` and map `moduleB` to `L1`. When code in `moduleB` tries to resolve a reference to a class in its own module then it will be loaded by `L1` (no delegation). When `moduleB` references a class in `java.base` then `L1` will delegate to the `boot loader`.

When `Child2` is created it will create `L2` and map `moduleC` to `L2`. When code in `moduleC` tries to resolve a reference to a class in its own module then it will be loaded by `L2` (no delegation). When `moduleC` references a `b.*` class then it will be delegate to `L1` to resolve the reference. When `moduleC` references a class in java.base then `L2` will delegate to the boot loader.

If you draw this out then you should see that the class loader delegation is "direct delegation" and exactly mirrors the edges in the readability graph (Configuration object).

Hopefully this is enough to get your started. It really needs diagrams and graphs to explain some of these details probably. As I said, you can mostly ignore class loader details when working with module layers.

Comment: @AlanBateman I've posted the corrected answer. Please, see if everything is right otherwise it can make someone crazy.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume the parent layer of Child2 is Child1.

---

Let's start with the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.6):

> Module membership is defined in terms of run-time packages ([§5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3)). A program determines the names of the packages in each module, and the class loaders that will create the classes and interfaces of the named packages; it then specifies the packages and class loaders to an invocation of the defineModules method of the class ModuleLayer. Invoking defineModules causes the Java Virtual Machine to create new run-time modules that are associated with the run-time packages of the class loaders.

The important part here is: When a module layer is defined, the package names for each module have to be known.

> A run-time module is implicitly part of exactly one layer, by the semantics of defineModules. However, a class loader may create classes in the run-time modules of different layers, because the same class loader may be specified to multiple invocations of defineModules. Access control is governed by a class's run-time module, not by the class loader which created the class or by the layer(s) which the class loader serves.

Class loader delegation is irrelevant.

> There are similarities and differences between class loaders and layers. On the one hand, a layer is similar to a class loader in that each may delegate to, respectively, one or more parent layers or class loaders that created, respectively, modules or classes at an earlier time. **That is, the set of modules specified to a layer may depend on modules not specified to the layer, and instead specified previously to one or more parent layers.** On the other hand, a layer may be used to create new modules only once, whereas a class loader may be used to create new classes or interfaces at any time via multiple invocations of the defineClass method.

(emphasis mine)

---

This should be enough to answer your question:

- Because the parent layer of Child1 is the boot layer, modules in Child1 can depend on modules in the boot layer.
- Because the parent layer of Child2 is Child1, modules in layer Child2 can depend on modules in Child1 and the boot layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think you missed the key point - how does `moduleC` see classes from `moduleB`, if it uses SystemClassLoader  as parent loader and SystemClassLoader starts to load classes from boot layer and up by, but not down.

Comment: For example, could you continue this sentence - We are in `moduleC` with `parentClassLoader = SystemClassLoader `and class from `moduleB` is required. To get this class the following is done...

Comment: Determine what classloader is used for moduleB (Module::getClassloader), and ask it to load the class.

Comment: Let's say you want to load the class `foo.bar.Baz`. Java takes the package name (`foo.bar`), and looks up the corresponding module (it uses the union of all modules in the current layer and all parent layers) - which is `moduleB`. Then it gets the corresponding class loader for that module. And asks that to load the class. It doesn't delegate to the parent loader.

Comment: Ok. But how will moduleC determine what classloader is used for `moduleB` if it has two classloaders - the classloader of `moduleC` and parentClassLoader?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then why do we pass parent loader? When is parent loader used?

Comment: For delegation for things that are not in a module. Resources, classes in the class path...

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ModuleLayer.html#defineModulesWithOneLoader(java.lang.module.Configuration,java.util.List,java.lang.ClassLoader)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much! I will take some time out to analyze the information you provided.